# How to select the version of ASP.NET file at compile time in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I am using Visual Studio 2005, .NET Framework 2.0. Now I started using Visual Studio 2008 (.NET Framework 3.5) too. I am getting an error when I am running the application saying that it could not load the type.
The error page shows Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0. Why is it so? I'm running in Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio 2008 support [Multi-Targeting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398197%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), meaning that you can develop applications against different versions of the .NET Framework using the same IDE.

If your solution was created with Visual Studio 2005, by default **it's going to continue using the .NET Framework 2.0 when opened in Visual Studio 2008**.

You'll have to manually [change the Target Framework version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) on your project's properties to `.NET Framework 3.5`.